# How to find String elemets of a format in a Groovy list

Tags: groovy

I have a groovy list as below

```
def permissions = [
    TESTENTITY.ADMINISTER,
    TESTENTITY.CREATE,
    TESTENTITY.DELETE,
    TESTENTITY.READ,
    TESTENTITY.UPDATE,
    TESTBEAN.ADMINISTER,
    TESTBEAN.CREATE,
    TESTBEAN.DELETE,
    TESTBEAN.READ,
    TESTBEAN.UPDATE
]
```

Am trying to find all the elements in the list of format "TESTENTITY" with less code. Is it doable?

Comment: Less code than what? Are those strings? What have you tried?

Comment: I am not sure why this question has been voted down multiple times.  Aside from the peculiar "less code" part of the question, it seems like a perfectly reasonable question.

Comment: Am a rookie groovy developer, I couldnt find much information on writing closures for groovy lists, I dont understand why my question is voted down

Comment: [**When should I vote down?**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down) @JeffScottBrown

Comment: @RanPaul Do you have list of enums? If yes, please update the title or let know if you are unable to edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way I interpret the question.
Not considering each element as a `String` but a collection of `Enum`.

```
enum TestEntity {
    ADMINISTER, CREATE, DELETE, READ, UPDATE
}

enum TestBean {
    ADMINISTER, CREATE, DELETE, READ, UPDATE, DONOTHING
}

def permissions = [ 
    TestEntity.ADMINISTER, TestEntity.CREATE, 
    TestEntity.DELETE, TestEntity.READ, TestEntity.UPDATE, 

    TestBean.ADMINISTER, TestBean.CREATE, 
    TestBean.DELETE, TestBean.READ, TestBean.UPDATE, TestBean.DONOTHING
]

permissions.findAll { it in TestEntity }
```

**Note:**
`DONOTHING` is added to `TestBean` just to show the difference.

Comment: The title says they are Strings. If they are enum, that might explain why the question was voted down.  The title is misleading.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this...

```
def matchingResults = permissions.findAll { perm ->
    // perm will be one element from permissions.
    // inspect it and return true if it should be
    // include in the results.
}
```

If those are strings in the permissions list, that might look something like this...

```
def matchingResults = permissions.findAll { perm ->
    perm.startsWith 'TESTENTITY'
}
```

Is that what you are looking for?